# Inserting row into MYSQL table with PDO doens't work

Tags: mysql, pdo, insert, row

When I try to insert a row into a MYSQL table with PDO, it doesn't seem to work. I get no error messages, but the row simply isn't added. This is my code:

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "website";
$username = "leon";
$password = "*censored*";
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname; dbname=$database; charset=utf8", $username, $password) or die("Can't connect!");
$sql = "INSERT INTO members(email, password, gender, firstname, middlename, lastname, zipcode, address, residence, telephone, activation)VALUES(:email, :encryptedpassword, :gender, :firstname, :middlename, :lastname, :zipcode, :address, :residence. :telephone, :activation)";
$register_user=$connect->prepare($sql);
$register_user->execute(array(':email'=>$email,
                  ':encryptedpassword'=>$encryptedpassword,
                  ':gender'=>$gender,
                  ':firstname'=>$firstname,
                  ':middlename'=>$middlename,
                  ':lastname'=>$lastname,
                  ':zipcode'=>$zipcode,
                  ':address'=>$address,
                  ':residence'=>$residence,
                  ':telephone'=>$telephone,                   
                  ':activation'=>$activation));
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried getting the error info? `echo $register_user->errorInfo();`

Comment: Does your table have a unique key which you are duplicating with this query?

Comment: @Kay Nelson yep. `$register_user->execute(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
VALUES(:email, :encryptedpassword, :gender, :firstname, :middlename, :lastname, :zipcode, :address, :residence. :telephone, :activation)";
```

there's a dot after `:residence.` instead of a comma `:residence,`

Comment: Wow, I feel really stupid right now. Can't believe I overlooked this. Many thanks mate!